# How can I place an asset image at given screen coordinates in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, image, swiftui

I recently started with XCode and for practice I deveoped a simple game usiing UIKit (not realizing it was being superceded by SwiftUI). At its core is the display of up to 300 small images (varies as the game progresses) at random locations in a rectangular area of the screen.

To place each image I used an imageView `imageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)`
and an `imageView.frame = CGRect(with calculated x, y, width and height values)`
and finally causing it to be displayed in the view with `view.addSubview(imageView)`

Can someone please point me in the right direction to translate this for SwiftUI. I've done lots of searching but can't find anything that helps directly.
The only thing I have found is the concept of using `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap a `UIImageView class`. Is that the way to go?
If so, how would I go about it?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ZStack` that's filled with images, each of which have a random [`position`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/absolute-positioning-for-swiftui-views).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<300) { _ in
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .position( /// here!
                        x: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenWidth),
                        y:  CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenHeight)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Images placed randomly on screen]

Comment: Hi @aheze do you know how to define a position inside a foreach but without it being random? I want that each image appears always in the same position.

Comment: @SaraRaquel like a grid or something? `ForEach` works with HStack and VStack which might help. Maybe [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)